# How nested deployments are enforced

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have Azure ARM parent template which has nested deployment of `Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts` which in turn has nested resource `Configurations`. I was able to successfully deploy entire template once, which in fact created `configuration` in automation Account. I manually deleted `configuration` inside automation account and tried running template again but this nested deployment is no longer triggered at all. There is no errors, just this nested deployment is not shown up at all in history. I would assume ARM thinks since it succeeded last time it does not need to deploy or something, not sure. What might be the problem?

Here is relevant parts of template. Neither ScaleSet no nested deployment `WorkerNodeDSCConfiguration` is triggered at all.

```
 {
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
  "name": "[variables('namingInfix')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', variables('appGwName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'))]",
    "WorkerNodeDscConfiguration"

  ],
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('vmSku')]",
    "tier": "Standard",
    "capacity": "[parameters('instanceCount')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "overprovision": "false",
    "singlePlacementGroup": "true",
    "upgradePolicy": {
      "mode": "Automatic"
    },
    "virtualMachineProfile": {
      "licenseType": "[parameters('LicenseType')]",
      "storageProfile": {
        "osDisk": {
          "caching": "ReadWrite",
          "createOption": "FromImage"
        },
        "dataDisks": [],
        "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]"
      },
      "osProfile": {
        "computerNamePrefix": "[variables('namingInfix')]",
        "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
        "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
      },
      "networkProfile": {
        "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
            "properties": {
              "primary": "true",
              "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                  "name": "[variables('ipConfigName')]",
                  "properties": {
                    "subnet": {
                      "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]"
                    },
                    "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                      {
                        "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'), '/backendAddressPools/', variables('bePoolName'))]"
                      }
                    ],
                    "loadBalancerInboundNatPools": [
                      {
                        "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'), '/inboundNatPools/', variables('natPoolName'))]"
                      }
                    ],
                    "ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": [
                      {
                        "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', variables('appGwName'), '/backendAddressPools/', variables('appGwBePoolName'))]"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "extensionProfile": {
        "extensions": [
          {
            "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
            "properties": {
              "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
              "typeHandlerVersion": "2.72",
              "type": "DSC",
              "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
              //"forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('DSCExtensionTagVersion')]",
              "settings": {
                "configurationArguments": {

                  "RegistrationKey": {
                    "UserName": "PLACEHOLDER_DONOTUSE",
                    "Password": "[parameters('registrationKey')]"
                  },
                  "RegistrationUrl": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]",
                  "NodeConfigurationName": "swarmHost",
                  "RebootNodeIfNeeded": true,
                  "ConfigurationMode": "ApplyAndAutoCorrect"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},

{
  "name": "swarmmanagerdeployment",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('swarmmanagerdeploymentTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('swarmmanagerdeploymentTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "swarmmanager1Name": { "value": "[parameters('swarmmanager1Name')]" },
      "swarmmanager1VmSize": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1VmSize')]" },
      "adminUsername": { "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]" },
      "adminPassword": { "value": "[parameters('adminPassword')]" },
      "dockerswarmstorageaccountName": { "value": "[variables('dockerswarmstorageaccountName')]" },
      "dockerswarmstorageaccountType": { "value": "[parameters('dockerswarmstorageaccountType')]" },
      "swarmmanager1NicName": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1NicName')]" },
      "swarmmanagerpublicIPName": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanagerpublicIPName')]" },
      "swarmmanager1SubnetRef": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1SubnetRef')]" },
      "swarmmanager1ImagePublisher": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1ImagePublisher')]" },
      "swarmmanager1ImageOffer": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1ImageOffer')]" },
      "windowsOSVersion": { "value": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]" },
      "swarmmanager1StorageAccountContainerName": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1StorageAccountContainerName')]" },
      "swarmmanager1OSDiskName": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanager1OSDiskName')]" },
      "swarmmanagerpublicIPDnsName": { "value": "[variables('swarmmanagerpublicIPName')]" },
      "RegistrationKey": { "value": "[parameters('registrationKey')]" },
      "RegistrationUrl": { "value": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]" },
      "LicenseType": { "value": "[parameters('LicenseType')]" },
      "_artifactsLocationSasToken": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]" },
      "_artifactsLocation": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]" },
      "privateKey": { "value": "[parameters('privateKey')]" },
      "serverCert": { "value": "[parameters('serverCert')]" },
      "CACert": { "value": "[parameters('CACert')]" }

    }
  }


},
{
  "name": "WorkerNodeDscConfiguration",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "resourceGroup": "[parameters('automationAccountRGName')]",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "template": {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiversion": "2015-10-31",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "name": "[parameters('automationAccountName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
          "properties": {
            "sku": {
              "name": "Basic"
            }
          },
          "tags": {

          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "swarmhost",
              "type": "configurations",
              "apiVersion": "2018-01-15",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('AutomationAccountName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "state": "Published",
                "overwrite": "true",
                "Source": {
                  "type": "uri",
                  "value": "[parameters('WorkerNodeDSCConfigURL')]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "[guid(resourceGroup().id, deployment().name)]",
              "type": "Compilationjobs",
              "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
              "tags": {},
              "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('AutomationAccountName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('AutomationAccountName'),'/Configurations/swarmhost')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "configuration": {
                  "SwarmManagerURI": "[reference('swarmmanagerdeployment').outputs.returnedIPAddress.value]"
                }

              }
            }

          ]
        }
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Updated question with template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its pretty hard to tell what is going on, but you can verify if something is going on by changing some vmss property, for example, to something else and running the template. it will revert it back to what it is in the template. It might be pretty tricky with the automation account stuff, because I would think it wouldnt trigger the compilation job, because the guid is the same and the resource is there already. you would need to provide a new guid each time (ARM cant help you with this, you need to do some randomization externally). Generally I prefer to use powershell to configure automation accounts compared to ARM.

You can also verify that the nested deployment is being triggered by looking at its timestamp, it should change (and it will). The resource is always deployed, but depending on your situation its properties might stay intact.

Comment: Guid is based off deployment name and hence shall change on each run, also configuration itself is missing and hence deployment still shall take place. I try to avoid powershell since it will be impossible to deploy from Azure UI. Nested deployment is not triggered at all as you can see from screenshot, how do I verify timestamp for it?

Comment: ah, i get what you are saying. the nested deployment details are available in the resource group you are deploying it (not the parent, the actual group you are deploying it), the vmss doesnt start because the nested doesnt finish properly

Comment: I found that if I remove dependency on `WorkerNodeDscConfiguration` from `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets` then deployment of VMSS is triggered. Nested deployment is still not triggered though regardless what I do, not showing up in respective RG or parent RG anymore. It used to show up there when it was triggered but not anymore

Comment: thats impossible. I've did this kind of deployment lots of times, it works exactly how I describe. it should be in the resource group called whatever you are passing to this parameter: `automationAccountName` unless its blowing up weirdly, try looking at the azure monitor to figure out latest events, look for errors or microsoft.resource/deployments/write or validate

Comment: So there are 2 issues, first VMSS is not being triggered if I add dependency on nested deployment `WorkerNodeDscConfiguration` and another one nested deployment itself is not being triggered at all. The only errors in ActivityLog is for writing deployments. Did I use wrong syntax for dependson[]? Why VMSS is not being deployed if there is dependency on `WorkerNodeDscConfiguration`?

Comment: Figured it out. It was due to dependency on second nested deployment which errors out and hence the rest of deployment steps were not taken.